# MPGS (Mastercard) Integration Security

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway

According to MPGS integration guide, if merchant wants to display receipt when payment completed successfully, MPGS will redirect to merchant site callback URL with the resultIndicator. Merchant site needs to compare resultIndicator with successIndicator stored previously.

Hackers can first launch the MPGS payment session without paying. Then pretend to be MPGS and brute-force attempt repeatedly by calling that merchant site callback URL with different resultIndicator until it matches the stored successIndicator. Merchant then thought that the hacker has paid.

Is this possible? If yes, how to avoid this loophole? Need to call Inquiry API when received callback without trusting resultIndicator?

Comment: How is the call back URL structured? Doesn't it include a nonce or similar to reduce the possibility of this? Is the data signed (e.g. MAC)?

Comment: The "successIndicator" stored on merchant server is from MPGS real-time response of a "create session" request triggered at server-side of merchant. I guess that was the reason why MPGS just included "resultIndicator" in the callback.